# Mathematical Concept In Multi-Dimensional Array Sorting

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I have found this code written online(not by me), and was hoping to get an answer on what the mathematical formula or concept is that makes this function work. I am curious as to how this person designed this. First, I will explain the requirements that the function must produce, then I will supply the code, and a link to a working code pen for further hacking. P.S. The problem uses the word "vector", but since this is Javascript, vector just means array.

**Function Requirements**

Given a vector of vectors of words, ex.
[['quick', 'lazy'], ['brown', 'black', 'grey'], ['fox', 'dog']].

Write a function that prints all combinations of one word from the first vector, one word from the second vector, etc.
The solution **may not** **use recursion**. The number of vectors and number of elements within each vector may vary.

*Example output*: 'quick, brown, dog', 'lazy black fox' etc.

**My Current Level Of Understanding**
I am already aware that by using the principle of multiplication, to find the number of possible combinations available in this scenario is to just multiply the lengths of each inner vector by each other. For this specific example, we get a total of **12**(2x3x2) different possible combinations. Where I fall off however, is inside the 4 nested for loops section of the program.

Whoever wrote the code, clearly understands some concept or formula that I do not. Just two examples, are the "previous" variable used inside the loops, and the strategic placement of where they decide to increment the j variable. It seems to me that they might be aware of some mathematical formula.

**Code**
Below is the code without comments. If you however go to this [codepen](https://codepen.io/DZuz14/pen/xrKrZr), I have included the same code with plenty of comments that explain how the program works, so you don't have to trace everything out from scratch. You can also test the output in the built-in console.

```
function comboMaker(vector) {

  var length = vector.length;

  var solutions = 1;
  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    solutions *= vector[i].length;
  }

  var combinations = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < solutions; i++) {
    combinations[i] = [];
  }

  var previous = 1;

  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {

    for (var j = 0; j < solutions;) {

      var wordCount = vector[i].length;
      previous *= vector[i].length;

      for (var l = 0; l < wordCount; l++) {

        for (var k = 0; k < (solutions/previous); k++) {
          combinations[j][i] = vector[i][l];
          j++
        }
      }
    }
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < solutions; i++) {
    console.log(combinations[i].join(" "));
  }
}

comboMaker([['quick', 'lazy'], ['brown', 'black', 'grey'], ['fox', 'dog']]);
```

Comment: I'm not aware of any mathematical "concept" or formula at work here. In any case the solution is incorrect. If you add an extra "vector" to the main "vector" the function calculates the correct number of "combinations" but it writes duplicates. See this: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PjwKNv

Answer (score 1):

You can consider combination of items as number in [mixed radix numeric system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixed_radix).
Radix for every position is equal to number of items in corresponding array (here {2,3,2}). Overall number of combination M is product of all radixes.

You can generate combination either

by making for-loop with counter in range 0..M-1 and separating every digit from this counter and getting corresponding item. Pseudocode

```
 M = ProductOfLengthsOfArrays
 for c = 0..M-1
     t = c
     combination = {}
     for i = 0..NumOfArrays-1
         d = t %% Array[i].Length   //modulo operation
         t = t / Array[i].Length    //integer division
         combination.add(Array[i][d])
     output combination
```

by counting in mixed radix from 0 to M-1

```
  if item is last in the array, get first item and increment the next array
  else get the next item in the same array
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your time, but I am going to delete this thread, as I need to go back to the drawing board, as my solution does not work, and serves little purpose on here. I will give this a look.

Comment: But you could create working solution with given approaches. Are they clear enough?

Comment: Somewhat. I'm not really sure what your code means under the sentence, "You can generate combination either by making for-loop with counter in range 0..M-1 and separating every digit from this counter and getting corresponding item."

Comment: Excellent. I appreciate the help, will hit this hard tonight. So for example say, M is 12, we create a for loop that loops through m minus one times(11)? Also, when you set t = c, does that also equal 11? Not sure what t stands for. @MBo

Answer (score 0):

A cooperation of `.reduce()` and `.map()` allows us to come up with a very efficient single liner answer for this question.

```js
var data   = [['quick', 'lazy'], ['brown', 'black', 'grey'], ['fox', 'dog'],['jumps','runs']],
    result = data.reduce((p,c) => p.reduce((r,fw) => r.concat(c.map(sw => fw + " " + sw)),[]));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks, I will check this out!